# MoveIt2 Tutorials Getting Stuck

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just trying out MoveIt2 on Humble (source install as described on MoveIt PikNik site [here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html)) and have an issue where some of the tutorials (those involving RvizVisualTools) are getting stuck.  Initially I encountered the problem in a VM but tried with a native install to the same effect.

I initially found the issue when trying the Visualizing in RViz tutorial ([here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/visualizing_in_rviz/visualizing_in_rviz.html)).  After some testing I found the issue also in other pre-packaged tutorial examples.

Those in particular I have found so far are `move_group_interface_tutorial`, `motion_planning_api_tutorial`, and `motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial`.  For each of these three here are my observations:

1. `move_group_interface_tutorial`:

- Gets stuck after first click of 'Next' button
- The planning result is played back in RViz but execution never seems to continue after the call to `move_group.plan(my_plan)`

1. `motion_planning_api_tutorial`:

- Never gets past first prompt for 'Next' button (i.e., clicks do nothing)

1. `motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial`:

- This one just works...

Via experimentation it seems the culprit is the addition of the `SingleThreadedExecutor` spinning in a separate thread but I can't figure out why some cases are working and others not (and getting stuck in different calls).

Anyone else seeing same/similar behavior by chance?

I will keep investigating but I felt the fact some of the tutorials were non-functional worth mentioning.

Thanks,
Brett

Update:
I just found this issue which I believe to be the same:
[MGI CallbackGroup doesn't trigger callbacks when running external Executor #1474](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/1474)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404996/moveit2-tutorials-getting-stuck/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2022-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to mark this as answered as I am pretty sure this Github [issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues/1474) (bug -- currently still open) captures my question.

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2022-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2